# Xcode not letting me open a specific project

Tags: macbook-pro, ios, finder, xcode, permission

When i try to open a specific project in xcode (i can open my other projects just not the most important one) i get this error

[image: error]

I have gone in "Get Info" and made sure my account had complete access, but i still get this stupid error and i have no idea why. I am also the administrator for my computer and logged into my only account for this computer (i have not made multiple accounts) Can someone please help. 
- Thanks

Comment: I am not sure, but if xcode projects are bundles of files you may have permissions to open the top level directory but not the subsequent subfiles and subfolders. Try chmod -r 777 /Users/username/pathtoproject file, and see if that allows you to open it.

Comment: but why am i not able to open it normally. I was opening it just fine yesterday and never made any changes to the administrative settings, but now its not letting me open it.

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't have a clue. I am just telling you how to modify permissions recursively to see if the permissions problem will go away.

Comment: i can also open the subfolders (classes) individually but it still wouldn't let me open them in a project.

Comment: Did you try the terminal command I wrote? You could also probably open the top level folder, get info on it, open the permissions and sharing section, and when you click to unlock the lock and select the gear, you can choose "Apply to subfolders" or something of the like to apply the correct permissions to all the files and folders within it.

Comment: i ran your terminal command but it didnt open the project. and the only options i found under the gear were to "reverb changes"

Comment: Weird, I tried messing with the owner and permissions but I cant make the gear only show me one option http://i.imgur.com/erW7n.png , maybe someone has a better idea about this than me.

Comment: well thanks for trying. I just need to get more people to view this question.

Comment: and more people to vote it up so it gets more views

Comment: Questions about programming tools should be off-topic, basing on the [FAQ](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq), with the exceptions reported in the FAQ.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I appreciate your vigilance about off-topic questions, but in this case it seems like XCode is incidental to the question - this question seems to be more about file permissions, and would likely be closed on Stack Overflow, so I'll allow it to stay.

Comment: @luca590: Where is the project located? On an internal hard drive or an external one. I'm thinking that if the project is on a server share, that may be the cause of the problems.

Comment: Another random idea that might help - check the `Console.app` for some clue. Maybe you get lucky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open terminal and type

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /path/to/project_folder
```

NOTE: the capital R in the command above. Obviously change the path to your project folder to what it actually is.

If that command works without error,  but you still cannot open the project, then it isn't in fact a permissions problem but another bug in XCode.

You're not the first person to report this error however. Hopefully the above sorts it out for you.  Let me know.

Comment: its giving me this

sudo: illegal option -- R

Comment: did you type sudo -R  or sudo chmod -R etc as per my answer?

Comment: ok it let me in. How did u do that?